# I tried running this script, but i kept getting not a group by error

Tags: oracle-12c, group-by, toad

```
select
  a.*,
  b.Start_Date,
  b.End_date,
  sum(b.cost) as total_Cost
from Ess.TZeewrld a
left join Ess.Wrldest b
  on a.account_number, = b.account_number,
group by
  b.Start_Date,
  b.End_date;
```

Comment: Is this for SQL Server or Oracle? They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.*, 
       b.Start_Date, 
       b.End_date, 
       sum(b.cost) as total_Cost 
  from Ess.TZeewrld a 
  left join Ess.Wrldest b on a.account_number, = b.account_number, 
 group by b.Start_Date, b.End_date;
```

For starters, assuming we're talking about Oracle (given the reference to TOAD), the `group by` clause must explicitly include every non-aggregate column, so specifying `a.*` in the `select` is going to be a problem. You need to name each non-aggregate column explicitly in both the `select` and the `group by` clauses.

Additionally, there is a syntax error in your `left join` clause: there should not be any commas after the column names.

Comment: toad plus "not a group by expression" is an Oracle error message.